# webpack-dev-server inside docker trouble

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a file structure like this:

```
/root-app
  /api
  /dashboard
    package.json
    yarn.lock
    Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
```

**/root-app/[docker-compose.yml](https://pastebin.com/Qw7ddnS8)**

```
dashboard:
  build: ./dashboard
  command: yarn dev
  volumes:
    - ./dashboard:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

**/root-app/dashboard/Dockerfile**

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
ADD package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
```

When I run `docker-compose up --build` folder `node_modules` in `/roor-app/dashboard` it's created but it's empty. Why? I should have my `node_modules` for local development.

**UPDATE 1**

When I using absolute paths rather than relative paths

```
dashboard:
  build: ./dashboard
  command: yarn dev
  volumes:
    - ./dashboard:/usr/src/app
    - ./dashboard/node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
```

I get this error:

```
dashboard | yarn run v1.3.2
dashboard | $ webpack-dev-server --mode development
dashboard | /bin/sh: 1: webpack-dev-server: not found
dashboard | error Command failed with exit code 127.
```

**UPDATE 2**

My new `/dashboard/Dockerfile`

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
```

and removed `- ./hms-dashboard/node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules` from `docker-compose.yml`, error from update-1 still here.

Comment: Try using absolute paths rather than relative paths.

Comment: Please see the update

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing on build currently running into an issue with exit code 0, but the node_modules will install.
I had an issue where the `devDependencies` where not  installing with yarn.

```
FROM node
ARG environment=development

RUN mkdir /client

WORKDIR /client
COPY . /client

EXPOSE 8080

RUN npm --version
RUN npm install yarn
CMD if ["$environment" = "development"]; then yarn install --production=false; else yarn install; fi
RUN echo $environment
CMD if [ "$environment" = "development" ] ; then yarn build && yarn start; else yarn build; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `/root-app/dashboard/Dockerfile` remove copy command as you are already binding the same directory using volume.

Also use COPY instead of ADD command in Dockerfile.

```
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
```

In docker-compose.yml remove the second volume 
`- ./dashboard/node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules` , As first directory (./dashboard) is already mounted (/usr/src/app/).

Let me see your output after these updates.

Comment: If I installed `node_modules` from my os host (outside the Docker), everything is working fine. Why node_modules does not save locally